# Utilizing latex syntax in powerpoint equation input, how to use \frac

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, latex

I am using office 2016 home & student edition. When inserting equation, I can use some latex syntex, e.g., `\rangle` for `>`. But for `\frac`, I did not get it work. There is `IguanaTex`, http://www.jonathanleroux.org/software/iguanatex/, can combine latex and powerpoint; mathtype commercial version has some capacity. But, to what extend powerpoint itself can offer latex syntax support, e.g., `frac`?

Seems it is common for office 2016
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/is-latex-input-in-word-2016-broken-it-works-in/9f53dff6-c1a2-4f59-a684-e401204aab2d

some link https://office-watch.com/2017/maths-equation-latex-improvements-word-2016/
suggests it is only for office 365 user :(

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! You can write the equation in MS Word as it has better support for Latex. Then when you have finish with the equation, copy and paste it to Powerpoint.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried in MS Word.  `\rangle` ok, `\frac{1}{3}` does not work (direct input latex syntax not using any template) :( not sure if there is any special setting

Comment: On the Equation tab, have you clicked on Latex before writing your equations?

Comment: On my PC, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyJd9.gif) in MS Word.

Comment: Thanks. Once I clicked the 'Latex' and it turns grey, then I type anything, the ‘Latex' symbol turns white, no magic appears...

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio, by the way, which software were you used to create the .gif movie, I can try to show my case

Comment: Licecap. It can be downloaded [here](https://www.cockos.com/licecap/licecap128-install.exe)